# whenever i try to import models.py in my main.py file it shows me sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, fastapi, openstack-python-api

```py
from xmlrpc.client import Boolean
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP, Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
from .database import Base

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default='True', nullable=False)
    created_at= Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable= False, server_default=text)
```

I couldn't find the error. When I try to create the tables using `models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)` it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MINTU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 125, in _init_items
    spwd = item._set_parent_with_dispatch
AttributeError: type object 'bool' has no attribute '_set_parent_with_dispatch'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

File "C:\Users\MINTU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got <class 'bool'>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, Boolean must not be imported `from xmlrpc.client` but `from sqlalchemy`

Second, the name of your table is not written as `tablename` but as `__tablename__`.

Third, `text` in `TIMESTAMP` must be called with an argument that I would let you adapt to your needs

```py
from sqlalchemy import TIMESTAMP, Column, Integer, String, Boolean
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import text
from .database import Base


class Post(Base): 
    __tablename__ = 'posts'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    title = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    content = Column(String, nullable=False)
    published = Column(Boolean, server_default='True', nullable=False)
    created_at= Column(TIMESTAMP(timezone=True), nullable= False, server_default=text('(now() at time zone "utc")'))
```